# MFMailComposeViewController not displaying in iOS 8

Tags: ios

When I run Xcode 6 and use the iOS 8 simulator, I am trying to load a MFMailComposeViewController, it does not come up. Instead I get this error...

"Warning: Attempt to present MFMailComposeViewController: 0x7c30c400  on ViewController: 0x7baf6000 which is already presenting (null)"

This exact same code has been working for almost a year now, unchanged.
Just to be sure, I ran my app in Xcode 6 with the iOS 7.1 simulator and it worked like before, perfectly.

Does anyone know how to display a MFMailComposeViewController view in iOS 8?
This seems like a simple task and I'm sure its an easy fix.

PS. Posting is NOT needed because it is standard code but here it is anyway...

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

//Current Date
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]  init];
NSDate  *date = [NSDate date];
//Ensure UTC DATE
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss UTC"];
NSString *myString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Feedback time at %@.<br><br>Name:", myString];
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

NSString *subject, *emailAddress;

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
subject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Feedback"];

//Set the Subject
[picker setSubject:subject];

emailAddress = @"xxx@example.com";

//Set the Receivers
NSArray *myReceivers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:emailAddress, nil];
[picker setToRecipients:myReceivers];

//It saves the file name as the same as Subject here!
picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;//UIBarStyleBlack;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having a similar problem but did not get the same message.  However on iOS 8 my Mail Composer would not display.  I was launching it from a button on a UIPopover.  I would show the Mail Composer and then a few lines of code later I called:

```
    [myPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Another thread on StackOverflow indicated that maybe it had something to do with another view controller being active.  So I moved my dismiss popover above the other call to show the Mail Composer and also made it not animated:

```
    [aboutPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
```

Now it works.

Comment: That was what it was. I was presenting it from a UIPopover also and I added the line to dismiss it prior to opening the MailComposer and it worked! thank you

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue on iOS 8, which worked fine on iOS 7 and before.

I presented my `MFMailComposeViewController` after user press a button in UIActionSheet. So, in previous implementation, I put the mail composer and show `MFMailComposeViewController` in `UIActionSheetDelegate` function:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

which was straightforward with the function name.

But, maybe caused by some UI animation conflict, showing `MFMailComposeViewController` and dismissing `UIActionSheet` at the same time makes `MFMailComposeViewController` not shown.

- Solution

My solution is putting `MFMailComposeViewController` showing in `UIActionSheetDelegate` function:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Which is called after the `UIActionSheet` animation.

Wish this could help someone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this worked. I am not presenting any other viewControllers prior to calling this method but if I dismissed viewControllers first it works...

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MFMailComposeViewController` no longer works on the iOS 8 Simulator.

If you tried on a physical device, can you try just presenting the picker without any other changes like so:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Its probably also worth checking what `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` returns

Comment: I did try it on the device with no luck.

Comment: I just tried it again on a different iPad with no luck

Comment: @Airtower What does `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` return? Did you try just running the two lines of code above? Do you get any messages in the console output? Do you get any kind of crash? are you importing MessageUI? `@import MessageUI;`

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, seems like the SDK8.0 builds MFMailComposeController as a popOver in IOS8 so you have to dismiss any other popOver. Here's an example of how it works.

```
-(void)sendMail{
    [[[self fatherController] sharePopOver] dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setMailComposeDelegate:[self fatherController]];
    [[self fatherController] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: also this issue only takes place in ipad since there are no popovers in iphone/ipod

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with UIActionSheet. MFMailComposeViewController does not show up while UIActionSheet is present (on iOS 8 only). Even if you dismiss it without animations. Waiting for 1 second resolves the issue shamefully. So I used UIAlertController (introduced in iOS 8) for new devices and UIActionSheet for old ones. I now have an ugly and very long code, thanks to Apple.

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem with using UIActionSheet. I put the MFMailComposeViewController showing in another UIActionSheetDelegate callback function `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

The MailComposer doesn't work on the simulator , but it works with devices(iOS 8).

Answer (score 0):

In the popover func just do that

```
    @IBAction func exportAsMail(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("exportAsMail", object: nil)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
   ///****animated have to be false not true


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I use to display the Mail Composer, and it works just fine on my version of Xcode 6.0.1 and my device (iPhone 5 with iOS8) :

```
-(void) showMailComposer {
    if(![MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot send mail\n%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__) ;
        return ;
    }

    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"default@gmail.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: I tried copying and pasting this exact code and using it but i get the exact same error.

Comment: It may be a long shot, but do you have the latest version of Xcode ?